# i need to choose more performance approach

Tags: c++, performance, qt

There is a QTabWidget containing custom widgets (all widgets are the same type). I need to update the contents of each of these widgets on a QTimer::timeout signal and I have two options for how to proceed:

1. for each new widget

```
connect(timer_name, &QTimer::timeout, widget_name, &WidgetClass::update)
```

2. the only connection of the timer to the handler slot

```
connect(timer_name, &QTimer::timeout, this, &ThisClass::onUpdateRequest)
```

void ThisClass::onUpdateRequest()

```
for (auto &each : qtabwidget_name->children())
    qobject_cast<WidgetClass*>(each)->update();
```

which approach would be better in terms of speed and memory consumption?

Comment: I doubt it makes any difference performance-wise; either way the program is iterating over a list of widgets and calling update() on each one.  That said, the only way to know for sure is to implement it both ways and see if you can measure any difference in performance between the two.

Comment: In the case of the "update()" method, both are equivalent since repainting will be done when necessary, it is not immediate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better think about using a Model and View solution, implementing your custom delegates and storing your data in your model, so the Qt internal MVC system will handle the updating of your table cells